# How do I capture keystrokes directly on the tkinter canvas?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter-canvas

I'm having trouble capturing keystrokes from the tkinter canvas.  The keystroke is captured properly if I bind it to a label widget but not to the canvas.  My code is here:

```
from tkinter import * 
root = Tk()

class keyPresser():  
    # For test purposes, move the rectangle and print a message.
    # Nothing is happening
    def handle_down_key(self,event):
        self.canvas.focus_set() 
        self.canvas.move(self.rectangle,10,10)
        print('Down arrow key pressed')

    def __init__(self):   
        self.canvas = Canvas(root, width=400, height=400)
        self.rectangle = self.canvas.create_rectangle( 
            0, 0, 20, 20, fill = "black")
        self.canvas.bind("<Down>", self.handle_down_key)
        self.canvas.focus()
        self.canvas.pack()

mm = keyPresser()
root.mainloop()
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Change line 16 to  root.bind("<Down>", self.handle_down_key)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go !

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()


class keyPresser():
    # For test purposes, move the rectangle and print a message.
    # Nothing is happening
    def handle_down_key(self, event):
        self.canvas.focus_set()
        self.canvas.move(self.rectangle, 10, 10)
        print('Down arrow key pressed')

    def __init__(self):
        self.canvas = Canvas(root, width=400, height=400)
        self.rectangle = self.canvas.create_rectangle(
            0, 0, 20, 20, fill="black")
        root.bind("<Down>", self.handle_down_key)
        self.canvas.focus()
        self.canvas.pack()


mm = keyPresser()
root.mainloop()
```